# Как в c# выбрать нужные ячейки из Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, position

В общем, есть документ excel в котором есть 2 нужных столбца. Столбцы с данными от J7 до n и от K7 до n.

Как мне установить начальную позицию на эти ячейки и считывать столбцы пока J7+n != null и K7+n != null ?

```
var workbook = new Workbook(PathToFile);
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
var positions = ???
???
foreach (Row row in positions)
{
    var item = new Disclaimer
    {
        Count = (int) row[J7 + n].Value,
        Price = (decimal) row[K7 + n].Value
    };

    Items.Add(item);
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил сам. Может кому пригодится. row[9] - это ячейка соответствующая ячейке столбца J. (J - 10-я буква англ. алфавита, 9-я в коде потому что начинается счет с 0). Следовательно row[10] - столбец K.

```
var workbook = new Workbook(PathToFile);
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
var positions = worksheet.Cells.Rows.Cast<Row>().ToArray().Where(row => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row[9].StringValue) && row[9].Value is int);

foreach (Row row in positions)
{
    var item = new Disclaimer
    {
        Count = (int) row[9].Value,
        Price = (double) row[10].Value
    };
    Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Да,я тоже так решил для себя.
Главное запомнить,что в excel счет начинается с 1,а не с 0.